# Hunting Down Save Result Bug

Tags: breeze

I was looking for help trying to hunt down a bug with `hasChanges` still true after returning from a successful `saveChanges`. I am saving an entity and nested entity together and when it returns my `saveResult` is showing as an array with the first object showing the parent entity and the second object is a `$ref`. However one of my `entityGroups` is saying it still has changes so it acts like it needs to save again.

One interesting thing is that I saved a different set with a different nested entity and it returned with the nested entity as the first object in the `saveResult` array and my parent entity was the `$ref`. I did my best to make sure that both nested entity models looked the same. If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I will gladly give them a try and hopefully solve this issue.

```
{  
   "$id":"1",
   "$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.SaveResult, Breeze.ContextProvider",
   "Entities":[  
  {  
     "$id":"2",
     "$type":"CoreDBCodeFirst.Person, CoreDBCodeFirst",
     "LastName":"Washington",
     "FirstName":"George",
     "MiddleName":null,
     "SocialSecurity":null,
     "DateOfBirth":"1974-12-10T06:00:00.000Z",
     "Gender":"M",
     "Language":"en-US",
     "IdNumber":null,
     "Eligibility":true,
     "Active":true,
     "PersonAddresses":[  
        {  
           "$id":"3",
           "$type":"CoreDBCodeFirst.PersonAddress, CoreDBCodeFirst",
           "Address1":"13000 S Dakota 244",
           "Address2":null,
           "Zip":"57751",
           "City":"Keystone",
           "State":"SD",
           "IsPrimary":false,
           "Active":true,
           "PersonId":20118,
           "Person":{  
              "$ref":"2"
           },
           "id":20108
        }
     ],
     "FullName":"Washington, George",
     "Email":null,
     "id":20118
  },
  {  
     "$ref":"3"
  }
  ],
  "KeyMappings":[  
  {  
     "$id":"4",
     "$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.KeyMapping, Breeze.ContextProvider",
     "EntityTypeName":"CoreDBCodeFirst.Person",
     "TempValue":-1,
     "RealValue":20118
  },
  {  
     "$id":"5",
     "$type":"Breeze.ContextProvider.KeyMapping, Breeze.ContextProvider",
     "EntityTypeName":"CoreDBCodeFirst.PersonAddress",
     "TempValue":-2,
     "RealValue":20108
  }
  ],
  "Errors":null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you see a return value of a function in place of an entity, it's a good bet that there is something wrong with your metadata; usually having to do with the definition of one of your navigation properties.  Can you post the metadata for Person and PersonAddresses?

Answer (score 0):

Need more details.

What is the server tech?

What was your `saveChanges` call? Did you specify entities to save or ask to save the entire cache?

In a debugging session, capture the list of entities you're saving (`manager.getChanges()`) and compare them to the `saveResult.entities` in the response; are any entities missing?

Is anything remarkable about the unsaved entities after save?

Comment: I am using EF 6.1.0 for server tech. I am specifying the type of entities to save. When checking my `manager.getChanges()` I have an array of two entities. When it returns the `saveResult.entities` is an array with the first being the same and the second item in the array is a function `function () { return mappingContext.refMap[nodeRefId]; }]`

Comment: I *know* this one. I just can't remember it :(   Please paste the serialized response from the server for those two entities. I suspect that there is a mismatch between a `$id` and the `$refId` associated with that second item.

Comment: What do you mean "specifying the type of entities to save"? That isn't an option. You can specify an array of entities or nothing. But you can't specify the type of entities to save.

Comment: Edited question with response. And I meant specifying the array when I said "specifying the type of entities to save", so I wasn't trying to stray in a different direction there.